# Mi validador personalizado no funciona, Angular 6, Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intentando hacer una validación personalizada para mi formulario.
Tengo un servicio que comprueba en mi base de datos si la referencia es valida.

Una vez comprobada la referencia, asigno un valor boolean a una variable, en funcion de ese valor me gustaría validar o no el formulario.

El código del controlador es:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dataForm: FormGroup;
  controlref: boolean;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      ref: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateRef(this.controlref)]],
    })
  }

  changeControlRef(article: boolean) {
    this.controlref = !this.controlref;
    console.log('aqui',this.controlref)

  }

  validateRef(controlref: boolean) {

    return () => {
      if (controlref) {

        return { 'validRef': true };
      } else {

        return { 'validRef': false };
      }
    }
  }



}
```

Dejo aqui el [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ks6wis)

// La funcion changeControlRef() simula la asignación de mi servicio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es tu método validateRef, que crea una clausura sobre el valor inicial de this.controlRef (que es `undefined`):

```js
class Ejemplo {
 
  constructor(value) {
    this.ref=value;
    this.clausura=this.show(this.ref);
  }
 
  show(controlref) {
  //controlref es un valor accesible por la función declarada, pero no
  // está asociado con this.ref
    return () => {
      console.log(controlref);
    }
  }
}

let e= new Ejemplo(true);
e.clausura();
e.ref=false; //esta modificación no afecta a la clausura
e.clausura();
```

Realmente no necesitas esa clausura, accede directamente a `this.controlref`:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      ref: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateRef.bind(this)]],
    })
  }

  ...

  validateRef() {
    if (this.controlref) {
      return { 'validRef': true };
    } else {
      return { 'validRef': false };
    }
  }
```

Funcionando en un [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uye6u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: creo entender lo que me quieres decir Pablo, podrias aplicarlo sobre mi stackblitz? es que yo he probado pero algo sigue fallando... Gracias!

Comment: Lo tengo! gracias pablo todo perfecto, olvide agregar el this ^^, ahora lo que necesito es 3 cafés y entender que es esto... todavia soy un newbie jeje

Comment: Un detalle me gustaría comentar... necesitas agregar un return null... sino no es valido el formulario en ningún caso, cierto?

Comment: Correcto, los validadores devuelven `null`para indicar que no hay errores